# How to hide or show html tags with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 div tags in my HTML code and I have defined a class by which I can expand or hide them.The problem that I have is the fact that when I click on one of the the value of the other changes.

```
<HTML>

    <BODY>
        <FORM>
            <script language="JavaScript">
                function setVisibility(id) {
                    if (document.getElementById('btnshowhide').value == '-') {
                        document.getElementById('btnshowhide').value = '+';
                        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('btnshowhide').value = '-';
                        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';
                    }
                }
            </script>
            <FIELDSET style="width: 600px;">
                <LEGEND>
                    <input type=button name=type id='btnshowhide' value='+' onclick="setVisibility('div1');" ;/>Insert Data:</LEGEND>
                <DIV id="div1" style="display: none;">
                    <LABEL for="351fef76-b826-426f-88c4-dbaaa60f886b">Name:</LABEL>
                    <TEXTAREA id="351fef76-b826   -426f-88c4-dbaaa60f886b" name="txtname" value="Name" type="text" title="Name:">Name</TEXTAREA>
                    <BR>
                    <LABEL for="02973dcc-5677-417c-a9bf-1578f58923ef">Family:</LABEL>
                    <TEXTAREA id="02973dcc-5677-417c-a9bf-1578f58923ef" name="txtFamiy" value="Family" type="text" title="Family:">Family</TEXTAREA>
                    <BR>
                </DIV>
            </FIELDSET>
            <BR>
            <FIELDSET style="width: 600px;">
                <LEGEND>
                    <input type=button name=type id='btnshowhide' value='+' onclick="setVisibility('div2');" ;/>Insert Data:</LEGEND>
                <DIV id="div2" style="display: none;">
                    <LABEL for="d8876943-5861-4d62-9249-c5fef88219fa">Type of property</LABEL>
                    <SELECT id="d8876943-5861-4d62-9249-c5fef88219fa" name="PropertyType" value="" type="select" title="Type of property"></SELECT>
                    <BR>
                </DIV>
            </FIELDSET>
            <BR>
        </FORM>
    </BODY>

</HTML>
```

I tried changing the Ids of my buttons but nothing changed.

Comment: You should use classes instead of ids if they have the same name.

Comment: `id` of element has to be unique. You are having same if assigned to two buttons.

Comment: @SachinG:I have already tried changing the IDs but it did not work.

Comment: Is my question worth down voting????

Comment: check out my answer. Question is downvoted maybe because this kinda of question are already asked before and have answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change you buttons to --

```
<input type="button" name="type" id="btnshowhide1" value="+" onclick="setVisibility('div1',this.id);";/> 

and 

<input type="button" name="type" id="btnshowhide2" value="+" onclick="setVisibility('div2',this.id);";/>
```

And use following function --

```
function setVisibility(id,buttonid) {
  if(document.getElementById(buttonid).value=='-'){
        document.getElementById(buttonid).value = '+';
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  }
else{
        document.getElementById(buttonid).value = '-';
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';
  }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Zsuvq/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn`t have two elements with same ID. You should use class for it.

And it happens because you have both buttons with `id="btnshowhide"` so when you are trying to do `document.getElementById('btnshowhide').value` it matches you both buttons.

you can do something like this

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function setVisibility(id,input) 
{
    if(input.value=='-')
    {
        input.value = '+';
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
    else
    {
        input.value = '-';
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'inline';
    }
}
</script>
```

and in your inputs

```
onclick="setVisibility('div1', this);"
onclick="setVisibility('div2', this);"
```